# Automatic user profile after registration

Tags: php, directory, registration, mkdir

I'm interested in which code I should use in order for the user to have a profile, pictures and so on in their folder after registration. I put the code in but just make an empty folder.

**register.php**

```
<?php
    require('db.php');
    if (isset($_REQUEST['username'])) {
        $username = stripslashes($_REQUEST['username']);
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $username);
        $email    = stripslashes($_REQUEST['email']);
        $email    = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $email);
        $password = stripslashes($_REQUEST['password']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $password);
        $create_datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $query    = "INSERT into `users` (username, password, email, create_datetime)
                     VALUES ('$username', '" . md5($password) . "', '$email', '$create_datetime')";
        $result   = mysqli_query($con, $query);
        mkdir("users/".$username);
        if ($result) {
            echo "<div class='form'>
                  <h3>You are registered successfully.</h3><br/>
                  <p class='link'>Click here to <a href='connect.php'>Login</a></p>
                  </div>";
        } else {
            echo "<div class='form'>
                  <h3>Required fields are missing.</h3><br/>
                  <p class='link'>Click here to <a href='connect.php'>registration</a> again.</p>
                  </div>";
        }
        
    } else {
?>

<?php 
}
?>
```

What do I need to add or change to automatically insert a profile page that I create?

Before this I only made a profile page and the ability to post pictures, but all the pictures were posted on the same profile so I wanted to make sure everyone has their own profile.

Comment: You need to stop using md5 for password storage, use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` instead. You also need to use prepared statements instead of concatenating strings into your query. I know that doesn't answer the question you asked.

Comment: As for your actual question, any additional profile data just needs to go in whatever is the most appropriate location in a normalised database. For picture storage, if it's just one profile photo I'd upload it to a unique name, and store that name in the users profile row. If you want more than one photo, upload them all to a unique name and have a second table containing the file name and the user-id to relate it to the owner.

Comment: Note also that there's no need for your `create_datetime` code - just set your `create_datetime` column in the database to default to the current date and time, and leave it out of your `insert` query altogether.

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should alway use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: I made it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities.

Generally speaking, just create a new profile entity, similar to user entity you created `[username, password, email, create_datetime]`

The problem is however saving a picture in mysql is not the best way to store images, but this is possible using a BLOB field or saving the image encoded as base64.

Other more common approach is to store image using the CMS system - the system that manages all content of the website. Such systems usually store the images as files, in this case the database will contains the image name that allows to access it from the filesystem.